# boost::asio::io_service check if null

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am using boost 1.55 ([io_service doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html)).  I need to call the destructor on my io_service to reset it after power is cycled on my serial device to get new data.  The problem is that when the destructor is called twice (re-trying connection), I get a segmentation fault.

In header file

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service_port_1;
```

In function that closes connection

```
io_service_port_1.stop();
io_service_port_1.reset();
io_service_port_1.~io_service();    // how to check for NULL?
                                    // do I need to re-construct it?
```

The following does not work:

```
if (io_service_port_1)
if (io_service_port_1 == NULL)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't destroy an object twice. Once it's destroyed it's gone. Since you call the destructor explicitly are you bothering to instantiate a new instance of the object? Why are you explicitly calling the destructor anyway?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I state my reason above (serial device power cycled).  How do I instantiate a new instance of the `io_service`?

Comment: Allocate it on heap and set it to null the first time when you destroy it ? Or probably use `boost::optional` if it provides some mechanism to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need manual control over when the object is created and destroyed, you should be wrapping it in a `std::unique_ptr` object.

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> service_ptr = 
    std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service>();

/*Do stuff until connection needs to be reset*/
service_ptr->stop();
//I don't know your specific use case, but the call to io_service's member function reset is probably unnecessary.
//service_ptr->reset();
service_ptr.reset();//"reset" is a member function of unique_ptr, will delete object.

/*For your later check*/
if(service_ptr) //returns true if a valid object exists in the pointer
if(!service_ptr) //returns true if no object is being pointed to.
```

Generally speaking, you should never directly call `~object_name();`. Ever. Ever. Ever. There's several reasons why:

- As a normal part of Stack Unwinding, this will get called anyways when the method returns.
- `delete`ing a pointer will call it.
- "Smart Pointers" (like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) will call it when they self-destruct.

Directly calling `~object_name();` should only ever be done in rare cases, usually involving Allocators, and even then, there are usually cleaner solutions.